# How do you position Material UI Popper in the bottom right corner of the browser?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, popper.js

I'm using Material UI v4.9.1. They have a `Popper` React component, based on Popper.js v1.14.1.

- https://material-ui.com/api/popper
- https://popper.js.org/docs/v1

I'm trying to render a small square card on the bottom right corner of my browser.

With plain CSS, I think I would have to do this.

```css
.card {
    position: 'fixed';
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

I was trying to do that with the `Popper` component, but I'm not sure how. This is what I have now.

```
<Popper
    open={anchor !== null}
    placement="bottom-end"
    anchorEl={anchor}
    popperOptions={{positionFixed: true}}
    modifiers={{
        // I think I need some modifier?...
    }}
>
    {/* card component */}
</Popper>
```

I'm setting `anchor = document.body` when the user clicks a button. I've also set

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
}
```

in my root `index.html`.

However, when the `Popper` appears it's in the top right corner. The `div` has this style set.

```css
position: fixed;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
transform: translate3d(1164px, 5px, 0px);
will-change: transform;
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 15):

check [offset](https://popper.js.org/docs/v1/#modifiers..offset)

```
<Popper
  className='popper-root'
  open={open}
  anchorEl={anchorEl}
  placement='bottom-end'
  modifiers={{
    offset: {
    enabled: true,
    offset: '0, 30'
   }
  }}
>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try to set css on `Popper`.

```
<Popper
    open={anchor !== null}
    style={{ position: 'fixed', bottom: 0, right: 0, top: 'unset', left: 'unset' }}
>
    {/* card component */}
</Popper>
```

But this may not be the best solution, maybe you should write the component yourself, because this feature doesn't seem complicated, it may not be necessary to use `Popper`.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `anchorEl={anchor}` prop or set it to undefined, popper content will be child of `<body>` tag, please double check `disablePortal` prop (default is false) (follow official document: https://material-ui.com/api/popper/#props).

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

The Popper may appear in the top corer if there is not enough space under the body to draw it. It might be wrapping around and appearing at the top. Try and set your body height to 50% and see if it appears below it.

Answer (score 0):

Using @mui/x-date-pickers": "^6.5.0"
In the slotProps add

```js
popper: {
          placement: "bottom",
         },
```